# Cancel NSOperation completionblock

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperation

I have an `NSOperation` and in the `completionblock` I do some time consuming saving to CoreData. The actual operation runs fast. Occasionally I need to prevent this `completetionblock` from running. I can't see an easy way to cancel it so I tried setting a `BOOl` and skipping the code within it if necessary. However the operation is run within a singleton and another class needs to run the queue (that's why I need to cancel the `completionblock`). Any ideas on how I can cancel the `completeionblock`?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set `completionBlock` to `nil`:

```
operation.completionBlock = nil
```

But I think that cancelling operation's completion block from another class might be a design smell. You can end up with code which is hard to maintain and debug, as it's not clear why and when the operation's flow was changed.

Comment: @Michael: Wrong. Cancelling an operation from another class is absolutely common. For long running operation, you will often even have a "Cancel" button in the UI that will cancel the operation. It's an essential part of the NSOperation class that operations can be cancelled from the outside. And setting the completionBlock to nil isn't going to do anything once the completion block is running.

Comment: @gnasher729 Are you saying it's not possible to cancel the completion block?

Comment: @gnasher729 I thought we're talking about situation when the completion block hasn't started running yet. In such a case setting completion block to `nil` will prevent it from running. Also I was referring to cancelling the completion block, not the operation itself (which is a common thing to do).

Comment: Cancelling a completion block is not impossible, but difficult. A completion block has no interface. So it would need to get the information that it is supposed to be cancelled from elsewhere. That's the reason why you have NSOperation; you have an identifiable object on which you can call a cancel method.

Answer (score 0):

An NSOperation that runs fast with a time consuming completion block seems wrong. NSOperation can be cancelled, that's its main purpose. blocks cannot be cancelled unless you do all the work itself.

I'd suggest creating a subclass of NSOperation which does all the work, including what is now done in the completion block, and the code that is now in the completion block can check that it is cancelled.

On the other hand, "saving to CoreData" doesn't seem to be something you can just cancel half way through, so the better suggestion might be to take a step back and figure out what you actually want to happen.

Comment: Subclassing the operation would be tricky (it's already a subclass belonging to a third-party framework). I think I need to re-examine the design.

Answer (score -1):

You can cancel the operation by calling cancel method of NSOperation.

[operation cancel];

Comment: I'm not trying to cancel the operation, I'm trying to cancel the completion block.